# Does a comment before deleting a question make sense?

Tags: support, comments, notifications

I was notified in a comment that a question of mine is off topic. I am going to delete it and I was wondering if it is good to reply to the comment, like *'Accepted, I am deleting the question'*. Will the user be notified for my comment, even if I delete everything the very next second?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the answer here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231990/260340

Users will only be notified of comments left by a moderator on their posts in the last hour. In your situation, the notification for your comment will be cleared if your post is deleted.